# installation of postgis33_15 on Rocky Linux 8 fails

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgis-installation

When I try to install postgis33_15 on Rocky Linux 8, I end up with the following error

```
package postgis33_15-3.3.1-1.rhel8.x86_64 from pgdg15 requires gdal35-libs >= 3.5.2, but none of the providers can be installed
 package postgis33_15-3.3.1-1.rhel8.x86_64 from pgdg15 requires libgdal.so.31()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
...
 conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libarmadillo.so.10()(64bit) needed by gdal35-libs-3.5.3-4.rhel8.x86_64 from pgdg-common
```

internet suggests to enable EPEL and crb, but it's already done (CRB is showing up under name powertools)

```
sudo dnf repolist
repo id        repo name
appstream      Rocky Linux 8 - AppStream
baseos         Rocky Linux 8 - BaseOS
epel           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
extras         Rocky Linux 8 - Extras
pgdg-common    PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 8 - x86_64
pgdg12         PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 8 - x86_64
pgdg13         PostgreSQL 13 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 8 - x86_64
pgdg14         PostgreSQL 14 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 8 - x86_64
pgdg15         PostgreSQL 15 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 8 - x86_64
pgdg16         PostgreSQL 16 for RHEL / Rocky / AlmaLinux 8 - x86_64
powertools     Rocky Linux 8 - PowerTools
```

so now I wonder what am I missing :) Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/archive.fedoraproject.org/epel/8.8.2023-11-14/Everything/x86_64/Packages/a/armadillo-10.8.2-1.el8.x86_64.rpm

Install `rpm -ivh armadillo-10.8.2-1.el8.x86_64.rpm` or `rpm -Uvh --oldpackage armadillo-10.8.2-1.el8.x86_64.rpm`

```
dnf install postgis33_15 --exclude=armadillo*
```

or wait for update from PostgreSQL repo

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in today's update set. New **GDAL** version is `3.6.4-6`.

*FWIW*, please report these issues to
https://redmine.postgresql.org/projects/pgrpms/issues/new
or send an email to
`pgsql-pkg-yum@lists.postgresql.org`